# Check if some Intervals are evenly spread across a Timeline

Tags: math, time

I currently have the problem that I need to compute some characteristic number (would be good if its in 0-1 range) for the "evenness" of event starts.

I have various Timeslots which consist of a start date and a duration. I also have a fixed Interval where these Timeslots can occur in, for example the fixed Interval would be a week from 10.07.2018 - 17.07.2018.

Then given some events in this week I want to determine if they are evenly distributed. Evenly distributed for me means that the distance between these events would be the same.

So if there are 3 events that are on 11.07, 13.07, 15.07 it should be considered better than if they all would occur on the 11.07.

Is there a mathematical algorithm or formula for this kind of problem?
Thanks in advance

Comment: this is not what i was looking for, but thanks ill try on mathematica.stackexchange

Comment: My bad, I meant https://math.stackexchange.com/